# Routing xhr/fetch requests on the background via PAC file

Tags: google-chrome, pac

Assuming I visit website `https://example.com` (as well as `https://tets.example.com`) I have a rule that will route all requests via proxy:
`if (host == 'example.com' || dnsDomainIs(host, '.example.com')`

But I need to route all background requests too, like to `google.com` or `www.gstatic.com` when they are originated from `https://example.com` website. I've looked over the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_PAC_file) but dont see any obvious way. I thought I could rely on `url` argument but it is not the web-site origin URL but rather the request URL, so it is pontless.